# Python, BeautifulSoup,

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```html
<div data-testid="hero-rating-bar__popularity__score" class="sc-edc76a2-1 gopMqI">39</div>
```

I am trying to collect the '39' in that HTML using:

```
pop = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "sc-edc76a2-1 gopMqI"})
```

How should I use the parameter data-testid?

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter `attrs` with key value pair, the same way as for the class in your example:

```
soup.find(attrs={'data-testid':'hero-rating-bar__popularity__score'}).text
```

or if you try to get a `ResultSet`:

```
for e in soup.find_all(attrs={'data-testid':'hero-rating-bar__popularity__score'}):
    print(e.text)
```

Same with using of `css selectors`:

```
soup.select_one('[data-testid="hero-rating-bar__popularity__score"]').text
```

or a `ResultSet`:

```
for e in soup.select_one('[data-testid="hero-rating-bar__popularity__score"]'):
    print(e.text)
```